# Using A Vue application as an SDK

Tags: javascript, vue.js, sdk, vue-component

We are creating the application with Vue.js, We want to have an SDK of our final application for some purposes. we want to give a bundle of our project to other developers from other companies . so they can reuse or customize or override our vue.js component on their own projects. **the destination project could be wrote by vue or not.**
Is that possible to have this feature?

Answer (score 0):

I would say this is possible without a problem. The SDK could be initialized by passing the id of the container the Vue.js instance should be created in. This should interfere in no way with other frameworks like React or Angular.

Comment: How? I mean we have to provide an script an then pass to the end developer or create a bundle with some bundlers like webpack and then pass it? Which way?